# How to listen to value change in react-native-reanimated?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-svg, react-native-reanimated

I have created a simple animation with `Animated` from `react-native` with `react-native-svg`.

This do the jobs well,

But Now I switched to `react-native-reanimated` cuz I read on their website that reanimated is faster than `Animated` from `react-native`.

But here I faced with a problem, and that is I cant find function `addListener` to listen to the value changes.

Code with `Animated` from `react-native`:

```
const circleRadius = new Animated.value(100);

circleRadius.addListener( circleRadius => {
       circleSVG.current.setNativeProps({ cx: circleRadius.value.toString() });
});
```

**How can I implement above `addListener` function in** `react-native-reanimated` ?

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Unfortunately Still I couldnt find a way for that

Comment: @Muhammad Have you checked this? https://software-mansion.github.io/react-native-reanimated/on-change.html#onchange

Comment: @vishtree according to the description, it seems to be a different thing

Answer (score 18):

You can achieve similar behavior using `Animated.call`. [Here](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/56/Conditional-JavaScript-Callbacks-with-Reanimated-in-React-Native) is a nice tutorial about the subject.

Edited:

For example, to listen to `circleRadius` changes, you could use this code:

```
  import { call, useCode } from 'react-native-reanimated'

  useCode(() => {
    return call([circleRadius], (circleRadius) => {
      console.log(circleRadius)
    })
  }, [circleRadius])
```

Does it do what you want?

Comment: didbt work as I want, please see once again my question

Comment: @Muhammad sorry to hear it. I'll add a minimal code example, maybe we don't understand each other :)

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please let me know where the `call` function comes from ???

Comment: Thank you very much, I am getting this error after updating as your code:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double.java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference

Comment: Also I am updating only the `cx` like this `circleSVG.current.setNativeProps({ cx: circleRadius.value.toString() });` so in your code what will be put to `cx' ?

Answer (score 3):

```
import React, { FC, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import Svg, { G, Circle } from 'react-native-svg';
import Animated, { call, Easing, interpolate, useCode } from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { timing } from 'react-native-redash';

interface DonutChartProps {
  percentage: number;
  radius?: number;
  strokeWidth?: number;
  duration?: number;
  color?: string;
  delay?: number;
  textColor?: string;
  max?: number;
}

const AnimatedCircle = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Circle);
const AnimatedTextInput = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(TextInput);

const DonutChart: FC<DonutChartProps> = ({
  percentage,
  radius = 40,
  strokeWidth = 10,
  duration = 500,
  color = 'tomato',
  textColor,
  max = 100,
}) => {
  const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);

  const halfCircle = radius + strokeWidth;
  const circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
  const maxPercentage = (100 * percentage) / max;

  const animation = timing({
    from: 0,
    to: 1,
    duration,
    easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.linear),
  });

  const strokeDashoffset = interpolate(animation, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [circumference, circumference - (maxPercentage * circumference) / 100],
  });

  const textValue = interpolate(animation, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, Math.round(percentage)],
  });

  useCode(
    () => [
      call([textValue], ([textValue]) => {
        if (inputRef.current) {
          inputRef.current.setNativeProps({
            text: `${Math.round(textValue)}`,
          });
        }
      }),
    ],
    [textValue]
  );

  return (
    <View>
      <Svg width={radius * 2} height={radius * 2} viewBox={`0 0 ${halfCircle * 2} ${halfCircle * 2}`}>
        <G rotation="-90" origin={`${halfCircle}, ${halfCircle}`}>
          <Circle
            cx="50%"
            cy="50%"
            stroke={color}
            strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
            r={radius}
            fill="transparent"
            strokeOpacity={0.2}
          />
          <AnimatedCircle
            cx="50%"
            cy="50%"
            stroke={color}
            strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
            r={radius}
            fill="transparent"
            strokeDasharray={circumference}
            strokeDashoffset={strokeDashoffset}
            strokeLinecap="round"
          />
        </G>
      </Svg>
      <AnimatedTextInput
        ref={inputRef}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        editable={false}
        defaultValue="0"
        style={[
          StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
          { fontSize: radius / 2, color: textColor ?? color, fontWeight: '900', textAlign: 'center' },
        ]}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default DonutChart;
```

Comment: as you can see in my code, I use `useCode` and `call` to change textValue smoothly.

Comment: How can i implement it with Reanimated V2 :(?

Answer (score 1):

Reanimated is meant to be a declarative API that allows you to run more advanced animations and thus complex logic on the native thread.

The reason something similar to `addListener` is not implemented is because it would require unnecessary messages between the native and JS thread. So rather than using a listener and `setNativeProps` to update the `cx` property of your circle, it would be best to use an `AnimatedNode`.

```
const circleRadius = new Animated.value(100);

circleRadius.addListener( circleRadius => {
       circleSVG.current.setNativeProps({ cx: circleRadius.value.toString() });
});
```

```
import { Circle } from 'react-native-svg';

// must make Circle compatible with Animated Values
const AnimatedCircle = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Circle);

// then within your svg
<AnimatedCircle 
  // ... add other props
cx={circleRadius}
/>
```

Comment: thank you, your code is same my code, so could you please show me whats your solution

Comment: Could you elaborate on your use case or add more of your code to the question? I'm not sure how or what is updating the AnimatedValue circleRadius